# Display comma separated data on Thingsboard in time series charts

Tags: csv, charts, thingsboard

I get comma spearated temperature data form a device, where the last entry is the last, the first one is from 1 hour before. The provided data is temperatures from the past hour by minute.

I get json data like this:

temperature   19.2,23.4,18.3 ......   23.0, 18.2

How to show it in Thingsboard in a time series chart with proper timing?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You might use [Rule Engine](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/re-getting-started/) to convert your JSON in the format you need.

Supposing you are able to send device data to the platform via [MQTT API](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/mqtt-api/#telemetry-upload-api) or [HTTP API](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/http-api/#telemetry-upload-api) with the following payload:

```
{ 
    "temp": [22, 3, 45] 
}
```

then with the [Script Transformation Node](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/transformation-nodes/#script-transformation-node) you can convert the payload (the `msg` field of the `POST_TELEMETRY` event) to a format like the one below, which can be stored on database and directly shown from timeseries widgets:

```
[{
    "ts": 1618296229874,
    "values": {
        "temp": 45
    }
}, {
    "ts": 1618296169874,
    "values": {
        "temp": 3
    }
}, {
    "ts": 1618296109874,
    "values": {
        "temp": 22
    }
}]
```

Also you might need an upstream [Switch Node](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/filter-nodes/#switch-node) if you have to distinguish between different kinds of telemetry formats. The resulting full working rule chain will be something like this:

[image]

Let's say your particular device is provisioned in Thingsboard with device type MULTIVALUE THERMOSTAT, you can configure the Switch node's function as follows:

```
function nextRelation(metadata, msg) {
    return ['other'];
}
if(metadata.deviceType === 'MULTIVALUE THERMOSTAT') {
    return ['multivalue'];
}
return nextRelation(metadata, msg);
```

This is the Script Transformation Node's function:

```
var tempArray = msg.temp;
var lastTs = Date.now();
var tsCounter = 0;
var MS_IN_ONE_MINUTE = 60000;
var newMsg = [];

for (var i = tempArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   let ts = {};
   ts.ts = lastTs - tsCounter;
   tsCounter += MS_IN_ONE_MINUTE;
   let values = {};
   values.temp = tempArray[i];
   ts.values = values;
   newMsg.push(ts);
}

return {msg: newMsg, metadata: metadata, msgType: msgType};
```

The Transformation function is just a starting point. You can improve it or make it more more accurate for you real needs.
In this example I assumed the input payload doesn't contain the *base hour* so I got it dinamically with `Date.now()`. So starting from the last telemetry, for all previous ones I calculated the corresponding timestamps going backward in time.

Comment: Thank you Alex! It help me a lot, and it works great with my small changes on different data but with the same structure. However I only get the result on the "Test script function", data is splited great, however I do not know how to access these data. "ts" is not shown in devices telemetries, temp is only the latest one. How can I work with these items on newMsg (as in this exact example)?

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your problem now. If you want to see time series values all together at the same time, you have to use dashboards with any timeseries chart widget, where the "ts" field will be automatically converted and displayed in a human readable datetime format. Device Last Telemetry panel on the other side (as the name suggests) will only show the latest telemetry for that device.